# Elliptic Curve using M2Crypto and BouncyCastle

Tags: java, python, cryptography, bouncycastle, m2crypto

Ok, I would like to sign using ecdsa in python, and then verify in Java. To do this I have developed a short python script using m2crypto, and a short java application using Bouncycastle.

It works if I generate the keys in python sign in python and validate in python, AND it works if I generate the keys in Java, sign in Java and validate in Java, but when I try to share the keys everything goes a bit pear-shaped. - I've been unable to share either from Java to Python or backwards.

What is below *should* work in that if you ran it you should get to the end of the java and it will 'fail' with a "check failed", but I can't find any errors in my code. I'm sure its probably a really simple/obvious bug:

**1) Key generation** (python, m2crypt):

```
from M2Crypto import EC
key = EC.gen_params(EC.NID_secp112r2) # Picked a random NID...
key.gen_key()
key.save_key("ecpriv.pem", None)
key.save_pub_key("ecpub.pem")
```

**2) Signature** (python, m2crypt):

```
def bigint(string):
    return int(string.encode('hex'), 16)

myhash = "hello" # Yes, this should be a sha1 of something but shouldn't matter?
key = EC.load_key('ecpriv.pem')
sigr, sigs = key.sign_dsa(myhash)

intr = bigint(sigr)
ints = bigint(sigs)

print (intr, ints)
```

the use of the 'bigint' is to turn it from the binary string returned from m2crypt into a big integer that the bouncy castle needs. I now copy and paste that into my application:

**3) Verification** (java, bouncycastle):

```
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.ECDSASigner;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECPublicKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ECPrivateKeyParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.util.PublicKeyFactory;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.io.FileReader; 

class ECVerify {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("EC Verification"); // Display the string.

        String strmessage = "";
        String sigr = "";
        String sigs = "";

        try {
            strmessage = args[0];
            sigr = args[1];
            sigs = args[2];
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Bad Argument?");
            System.out.println(e.toString());

            System.out.println("java ECVerify message r s");
            return;
        }

        try {
            PemReader reader = new PemReader(new FileReader("ecpub.pem"));
            PemObject poKey = (PemObject) reader.readPemObject();

            byte[] poContent = poKey.getContent();

            // Now we have a signature we have to try and verify       
            ECDSASigner mySignValidator = new ECDSASigner();

            ECPublicKeyParameters myPublicKey = (ECPublicKeyParameters) PublicKeyFactory.createKey(poContent);

            // From here down its all ok *I think*
            mySignValidator.init(false, myPublicKey);

            byte[] message = strmessage.getBytes();

            System.out.println("Message: " + byteArrToHexStr(message));
            System.out.println("Message: " + new BigInteger(sigr).toString() +" " +  new BigInteger(sigs).toString());

            boolean check = mySignValidator.verifySignature(message, new BigInteger(sigr), new BigInteger(sigs));

            if(check) {
                System.out.println("Check passed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Check failed");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in main:");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }

    // What follows are just convenience functions for printing

    public static String byteAsHexString ( byte b )
        {
                String rV = "";

                int k = (int) b;
                k = k & 0xff;            
                if ( k <= 0xf )
                {                
                        rV = rV + "0";
                }
                rV = rV + Integer.toHexString ( k );
                return rV;
        }

    public static String byteArrToHexStr ( byte[] bs )
        {
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                for(int i=0; i< bs.length; i++)
                {
                        sb.append( byteAsHexString ( bs[i] ));

                }
                return sb.toString();
        }

    public static byte[] hexStrToByte(String hex) {
        // look for sepeartor

        StringBuffer tempBuf = new StringBuffer(hex);

        for (int i=0; i<tempBuf.length(); i++) {
            char c = tempBuf.charAt(i);  
            if (!((c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')|| (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')|| (c >= '0' && c <= '9'))) {
                tempBuf.deleteCharAt(i);
                 i--;
            }
        }

        hex = tempBuf.toString();

        byte[] bts = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < bts.length; i++) {
            bts[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16);
        }

        return bts;
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: why not call verify_dsa in the python code to check?  and why not use a real hash?  not sure i would personally post code saying "this won't matter" when i have a bug...

Comment: I do call (ok not in that example) verify_dsa - as i mentioned, python -> python works ok. I'm trying to reduce the differences between the python and the Java to see where the problem lies: there isn't a sha in either. One thing I was beginning to wonder was whether the m2crypt was performing a sha internally.

Comment: Did you check your hexadecimal methods *thoroughly*? And if you did, could you check if the hexadecimal encoding of your message is the same on both platforms?

Comment: Yes (I had someone else check this) We did everything a second way and got the same answers (i thought perhaps the issue was the encoding of the byte array into a bigInteger etc, but it wasn't). After working on this for another two days, we have a solution now (after a LOT of messing around) and I'll get it cut down and posted. Basically it seems that m2crypto sign_dsa produces output which just isn't compatible - instead sign_dsa_asn1 produces a single ASN1 encoded output which contains (and can be decoded into) r and s components, which the Java can then validate. (I will post later!)